# Subir una imagen y guardarla en una carpeta con tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

estoy diseñando una GUI donde hay un formulario de carga de datos, que se guardan en un .txt y por otro lado debe subirse una imagen que va guardada en otra carpeta dentro del proyecto.

Con tkinter uso la propiedad de filedialog.askopenfilename para poder seleccionar una imagen a subir y uso print para que saber en consola si efectivamente la subió.

El problema se da al usar la propiedad filedialog.asksaveasfilename para guardar la imagen que se abrio con la propiedad anterior, ya que esta no la guarda.

Es la primera vez que uso esta propiedad, no se bien en que parte me estoy confundiendo.

```
def abrir_imagen():
        global abririmg
        abririmg=filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/", title= "Seleccione el archivo", filetypes=(("png files","*.png"),("all files","*.*")))
        
        print(abririmg)

    def guardar_imagen():
        global guardarimg
        guardarimg=filedialog.asksaveasfilename(initialdir="/", title= "Seleccione el archivo",defaultextension=".png", filetypes=(("png files","*.png"),("all files","*.*")))
        
        archivo=open (abririmg, "w")
        archivo.write(abririmg)
```